# Meteor - Cannot find my package on Atmosphere

Tags: meteor, package, publish

I published my Meteor package named [`d4nyll:epic`](https://github.com/d4nyll/epic) last night using `meteor publish --create`, and this morning I still cannot find it on [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=epic). Is there some sort of a moderation process or I did something wrong?

**How can I find my package on Atmosphere?**

Comment: any error while doing publish?

Comment: I see something strage in your `package.js` [here](https://github.com/d4nyll/epic/blob/master/package.js#L15). What you trying to add here ?

Comment: @ajduke No errors. That file is where the bulk of the logic for this package resides. Could it be because I set the version number to be `0.0.1`? It really should have been `0.1.0`, I will fix it tonight. But no errors were thrown anyhows

Comment: This was an apparent problem on their side https://github.com/percolatestudio/atmosphere/issues/330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem on their side. I just [filed an issue](https://github.com/percolatestudio/atmosphere/issues/330) and it got fixed.